# AWS CDK: Dynamo Db Access for Fargate Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cdk

I (AWS noob) am playing around with the aws cdk.
I want to build a simple Spring service running in fargate with a dynamodb as a database.
It seems like my service cannot access the dynamo because of some missing permissions.
In the Cloudwatch Logs I see this error message:

```
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: User: arn:aws:sts::xxxxxxxxxx:assumed-role/MyCdkAppStack-TaskDefTaskRole1EDB4A67-xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:UpdateItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-central-1:xxxxxxxxxxx:table/MyDynamoDbTable (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: XXXXX)
```

For permissions for the table, I thought it should suffice to grant the necessary permissions to the task role of the fargate service:

`props.dependencies.dynamoDb.grantReadWriteData(taskDefinition.taskRole);`

In the AWS console, it looks like the permissions should be there: When I go to the corresponding task, the corresponding role seems to have all permissions.

It is not working though, so obviously I am missing something or doing something wrong.
Any hints on how I can connect a fargate service with a dynamo db table in a cdk app?

Thanks, some tips would be greatly appreciated :)

Edit: Sorry for the delay... 
Stack:

```
export class MyCdkAppStack extends cdk.Stack {
constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props: MyCdkAppStackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const appId = 'myService';

    const table = new Table(this, 'MyDynamoDbTable', {
        tableName: 'MyDynamoDbTable',
        partitionKey: {name: 'Id', type: AttributeType.STRING},
        billingMode: BillingMode.PAY_PER_REQUEST,
        removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.DESTROY
    });

    let logDriver = new AwsLogDriver({
        logRetention: RetentionDays.ONE_WEEK,
        streamPrefix: "test-stream-prefix",
    });

    const vpc = new Vpc(this, 'cdk-my-vpc', {maxAzs: 2});

    new cdk.CfnOutput(this, "MyVpc", {value: vpc.vpcId});

    const cluster = new Cluster(this, "MyCluster", {
        vpc: vpc,
        clusterName: appId
    });

    const appImage = ContainerImage.fromEcrRepository(props.dependencies.appRepo, 'latest');

    const applicationLoadBalancedFargateService = new ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(this, "FargateService", {
        cluster: cluster,
        taskImageOptions: {
            image: appImage,
            containerPort: 8080,
            logDriver: logDriver
        },
    });

    table.grantReadWriteData(applicationLoadBalancedFargateService.taskDefinition.taskRole);
}
```

}

Task Role Policy after cdk synth:

```
"FargateServiceTaskDefTaskRoleDefaultPolicy63F83D6F": {
  "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
  "Properties": {
    "PolicyDocument": {
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Action": [
            "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
            "dynamodb:GetRecords",
            "dynamodb:GetShardIterator",
            "dynamodb:Query",
            "dynamodb:GetItem",
            "dynamodb:Scan",
            "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem",
            "dynamodb:PutItem",
            "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
            "dynamodb:DeleteItem"
          ],
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Resource": [
            {
              "Fn::GetAtt": [
                "MyDynamoDbTableC81ED735",
                "Arn"
              ]
            },
            {
              "Ref": "AWS::NoValue"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "Version": "2012-10-17"
    },
    "PolicyName": "FargateServiceTaskDefTaskRoleDefaultPolicy63F83D6F",
    "Roles": [
      {
        "Ref": "FargateServiceTaskDefTaskRole8CDCF85E"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Can you add the task role policy definition here (json) after obscuring the necessary sections? Please also add corresponding CDK code here in question to get a better visibility.

Comment: Can you please share the relevant stack code as well.

Answer (score 0):

This should help
https://greenchapel.dev/2022/02/18/aws-cdk-fargate-schedular-write-to-dynamodb/
https://serverlessland.com/patterns/cdk-fargate-dynamodb

```
const dynamoGatewayEndpoint = vpc.addGatewayEndpoint('dynamoGatewayEndpoint', {
  service: GatewayVpcEndpointAwsService.DYNAMODB
});

// Allow PutItem action from the Fargate Task Definition only
dynamoGatewayEndpoint.addToPolicy(
  new PolicyStatement({
    effect: Effect.ALLOW,
    principals: [new AnyPrincipal()],
    actions: [
      'dynamodb:PutItem',
    ],
    resources: [
      `${dynamoTable.tableArn}`
    ],
    conditions: {
      'ArnEquals': {
        'aws:PrincipalArn': `${fargate.taskDefinition.taskRole.roleArn}`
      }
    }
  })
);

// Write permissions for Fargate
dynamoTable.grantWriteData(fargate.taskDefinition.taskRole);

// Outputs
new CfnOutput(this, 'DynamoDbTableName', { value: dynamoTable.tableName });
```

}
}