# Fargate Service Cannot Write to DynamoDB Table (CDK)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam, aws-cdk, aws-fargate

I'm working through setting up a new infrastructure with the AWS CDK and I'm trying to get a TypeScript app running in Fargate to be able to read/write from/to a DynamoDB table, but am hitting IAM issues.

I have both my Fargate service and my DynamoDB Table defined, and both are running as they should be in AWS, but whenever I attempt to write to the table from my app, I am getting an access denied error.

I've tried the solutions defined in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62086821/aws-cdk-dynamo-db-access-for-fargate-service) post, as well as the ones it links to, but nothing seems to be allowing my container to write to the table. I've tried everything from setting `table.grantReadWriteData(fargateService.taskDefinition.taskRole)` to the more complex solutions described in the linked articles of defining my own IAM policies and setting the effects and actions, but I always just get the same access denied error when attempting to do a `putItem`:

> AccessDeniedException: User: {fargate-service-arn} is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:PutItem on resource: {dynamodb-table} because no identity-based policy allows the dynamodb:PutItem action

Am I missing something, or a crucial step to make this possible?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

---

Edit (2022-09-19):

Here is the boiled down code for how I'm defining my Vpc, Cluster, Container Image, FargateService, and Table.

```js
export class FooCdkStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const vpc = new Vpc(this, 'FooVpc', {
      maxAzs: 2,
      natGateways: 1
    });

    const cluster = new Cluster(this, 'FooCluster', { vpc });

    const containerImage = ContainerImage.fromAsset(
      path.join(__dirname, '/../app'),
      {
        platform: Platform.LINUX_AMD64 // I'm on an M1 Mac and images weren't working appropriately without this
      }
    );

    const fargateService = new ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(
      this,
      'FooFargateService',
      {
        assignPublicIp: true,
        cluster,
        memoryLimitMiB: 1024,
        cpu: 512,
        desiredCount: 1,
        taskImageOptions: {
          containerPort: PORT,
          image: containerImage
        }
      }
    );

    fargateService.targetGroup.configureHealthCheck({ path: '/health' });

    const serverTable = new Table(this, 'FooTable', {
      billingMode: BillingMode.PAY_PER_REQUEST,
      removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
      partitionKey: { name: 'id', type: AttributeType.STRING },
      pointInTimeRecovery: true
    });

    serverTable.grantReadWriteData(fargateService.taskDefinition.taskRole);
  }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to point out what you are missing, since you didn't include your code in the question. Make sure you are giving the appropriate IAM permissions to the ECS task role,, not the ECS task execution role.  The task role is what is used by code running inside the task.

Comment: Yea, I was trying to clean the code up a bit to post it as it's all over the place right now from me trying to get it to work. Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't the `fargateService.taskDefinition.taskRole` mentioned in the post already the task role and not the execution role?

Comment: I don't see you actually assigning anything to taskRole though, just referencing it later. I don't think that role is created by default (it certainly isn't created by default outside of the CDK). You need to create that role and give it permission to access the DynamoDB table, and then assign it to the task.

Comment: I believe the Fargate Service does create a default task role when it's created. I just checked my IAM console and I see two roles in there that reference `FargateServiceTaskDefEx` and `FargateServiceTaskDefTa`. Unless those are byproducts of one of my many attempts to get this to work.

Comment: Actually, looking at the IAM console now, I see this warning as it relates to the Fargate service and DynamoDB: Specify table resource ARN for the DeleteItem and 9 more actions. I find it odd that it's asking to specify the table are when I'm supposedly setting the grant on the table itself in the CDK code.

Comment: Sorry, I may have misread the permissions. there is a separate resource section that has the ARN for my table in it. It does say "One or more actions may not support this resource.", which I'm assuming PutItem is one of those actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently either order in which the resources are defined matters, or the inclusion of a property from the table in the Fargate service is what did the trick. I moved the table definition up above the Fargate service and included an environment variable holding the table name and it's working as intended now.

```js
export class FooCdkStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const vpc = new Vpc(this, 'FooVpc', {
      maxAzs: 2,
      natGateways: 1
    });

    const cluster = new Cluster(this, 'FooCluster', { vpc });

    const containerImage = ContainerImage.fromAsset(
      path.join(__dirname, '/../app'),
      {
        platform: Platform.LINUX_AMD64 // I'm on an M1 Mac and images weren't working appropriately without this
      }
    );

    const serverTable = new Table(this, 'FooTable', {
      billingMode: BillingMode.PAY_PER_REQUEST,
      removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
      partitionKey: { name: 'id', type: AttributeType.STRING },
      pointInTimeRecovery: true
    });

    const fargateService = new ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(
      this,
      'FooFargateService',
      {
        assignPublicIp: true,
        cluster,
        memoryLimitMiB: 1024,
        cpu: 512,
        desiredCount: 1,
        taskImageOptions: {
          containerPort: PORT,
          image: containerImage,
          environment: {
            SERVER_TABLE_NAME: serverTable.tableName
          }
        }
      }
    );

    fargateService.targetGroup.configureHealthCheck({ path: '/health' });

    serverTable.grantReadWriteData(fargateService.taskDefinition.taskRole);
  }
}
```

Hopefully this helps someone in the future who may come across the same issue.